# Array of Label. Primes Generator. JavaFX

Tags: java, arrays, javafx, label, primes

I am trying to develop a program to generate 10 prime numbers each time a button is pressed but I am struggling. The code to identify the primes is correct but I get the error NullPointerException probably because I am handling the Label Array badly. I'll paste the code below, thanks for any tip on what's going wrong.

```
public class PrimeGenerator extends Application {

    Button generate;
    Label listNumbers;
    int i;
    int multiple = 2;
    int number = 2;
    int z = 1;
    int t = 0;
    Label[] primeList;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        VBox root = new VBox();
        generate = new Button("Generate 10 more primes!");
        generate.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                primeList = new Label[10];
                while (i < primeList.length) {
                    multiple = 2;
                    while (multiple < number) {
                        t = number % multiple;
                        if ((t == 0)) {
                            z = 0;
                        }
                        multiple++;
                    }

                    // Here I'd like to add the prime number to the array while also adding the Label to the Vbox

                    if ((z == 1)) {
                        primeList[i].setText(Integer.toString(number));
                        root.getChildren().add(primeList[i]);
                        i++;
                    }
                    z = 1;
                    number++;
                }
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().add(generate);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Prime Numbers Generator");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: could you please add the stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot to initialize the array element

```
....
primeList[i] = new Label();
primeList[i].setText(Integer.toString(number));
....
```

You can also in one line

```
primeList[i] = new Label(Integer.toString(number));
```

For example

```
                if ((z == 1)) {
                    primeList[i] = new Label();
                    primeList[i].setText(Integer.toString(number));
                    root.getChildren().add(primeList[i]);
                    i++;
                }
```

Alternatively, you can pre-create elements in advance:

```
        ...
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            primeList = new Label[10];
            for(int labelIdx=0; labelIdx<primeList.length; labelIdx++)
              primeList[labelIdx] = new Label();
            while (i < primeList.length) {
        ...
```

Comment: I have declared it outside the void method and initialised it in the beginning of the button

Comment: @DavideTormene If you are initializing the individual labels, please edit your question to include the code that performs that initialization.

Comment: i have included all the code that i have written so far

Comment: the declaration is at the 10th line

Comment: @Davide Tormene you have declared the array variable on line 10 and initialized it on line 19 but there is no code that initializes an array element.  In java when you create an array, its elements are null and you need to initialize it. I will expand the answer to illustrate.